CMake cyclic dependency error with shared libraries on Linux
I'm encountering a CMake error when building a project with shared libraries that have cyclic dependencies:
CMake Error: The inter-target dependency graph contains the following strongly connected component (cycle):
  "B" of type SHARED_LIBRARY
    depends on "A" (weak)
  "OpenPhase" of type SHARED_LIBRARY
    depends on "B" (weak)
At least one of these targets is not a STATIC_LIBRARY.  Cyclic dependencies are allowed only among static libraries.
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

The error suggests that cyclic dependencies are only permitted among static libraries, but in my case, all involved libraries are shared.
Context:

The environment is Linux, where cyclic dependencies among shared libraries are not problematic.
Modifying the library structure or switching to static libraries is not an option at this time.

Question: Is there a way to configure CMake to bypass or "force" the generation of build files despite the cyclic dependency? If CMake cannot accommodate this, transitioning to it may not be feasible for this project.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Cyclic dependency are bad in general (between libraries, sources, classes, ...). Note this means all targets have to be shipped as bundle (not target can be delivered as stand alone library). So what is the rationale of having multiple library? To break a cycle usually you should extract another library which will break a cycle.

Using target_link_libraries(B A) in CMake means that creation of library B will use the library A. When treating cyclic dependency in that sense, it cannot be handled neither on Linux nor in any other environment. You may, however, create the library B without using the library A, even if B needs some symbols defined in A. (Such linkage would probably require additional arguments for linker to ignore undefined symbols). For model that behavior in CMake just do not call target_link_libraries(B A).

@MarekR I understand that cyclic dependencies are generally undesirable. However, resolving them is not feasible at the moment, which is why that wasn't the focus of my question. The reason for having two libraries is that they are intended to be shipped together, along with the source code for one of the classes. This setup allows one of the libraries to be recompiled as needed.
